# how would Caeser say "hodiē iānuae domuum sunt ātrae"?

Tags: pronunciation

this post has been editted to use macrons, using html eg ā is & amacr ; without the spaces as html, similarly the other vowels. But this trick cannot be used in comments. I suppose what you can do is to write a temporary post using this trick, cut and paste the macronised text, and then cancel the temporary post.

the main pronunciation question is how the uum of domuum is pronounced, versus say the ū of domūs, but I am interested in the entire pronunciation.

poring over the manuals, I crafted the sentence "hodiē iānuae domuum sunt ātrae",
which maybe is wrong, but is supposed to mean "today the doors of the houses are black".

The first answer below by Unbrutal_Russian gives an audio recording which seems plausible as to how it should be pronounced. He says the m nasalises the preceding u of domuum, so in fact the uu is not 2 consecutive identical vowels, but the um is an indivisible code, and the consecutive vowels would be u then um.

Caeser is to specify which era of latin, first century BC.

I think confusion can occur with less often used things, and genitive plural of houses would be less often used. The 1425 words book, gives 29 nouns of the 4th declension where the genitive plural ending is uum, I dont see -uum in any other noun declension tables. The course book I am using so far has only mentioned 3 declensions, but the 1425 words book gives 5 declensions and a 6th, the indeclinables, of which it gives 3: fās, nefās, nihil = nīl.

Comment: Q0: We have instructions on our meta for typing a [macron](https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2/79) and a [breve](https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/q/172/79). There are HTML entities and other solutions. You can also just go to those pages and copy and paste the letters in.

Comment: Does your textbook not have a section on pronunciation? They're usually at the front (and usually very rudimentary, but almost always present, in my experience). You may be interested in picking up a copy of Sidney Allen's *Vox Latina* regardless.

Comment: @Cairnarvon I will try and get the vox latina book.

Comment: By the way, why not come to chat? That is a good place for discussions like this: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36130/conloqvivm

Comment: And I have another suggestion: people prefer reading one question at a time, not several about a similar theme put together into one 'question'. That's not what the format of Stack Exchange is built for. Next time, you might want to split a question like this up into three separate ones.

Comment: the book is "A New Approach to Latin" by EG MacNaughton (M.A.) and TW McDougall (Ph.D). Have placed an order for Vox Latina, it will arrive next week. Have just completed my tax return, so am a bit stressed but will try to narrow down the question later. Earnings and tax both lower than usual! Will have a look at the chatroom.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133352/discussion-on-question-by-commenter-how-would-caeser-say-hodie-ianuae-domuum-su).

Answer (score 6):

[Hear me pronounce](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8h6pyircm02vgs7/hodie%20januae.ogg?dl=0) [ˈhɔd̪iʲeːˈjaːnuʷae̯ˈd̪omuʷõˑs̠ʊ̃nˈt̪äːt̪ɾae̯].

- I transcribe [õˑ] as half-long because nasal vowels are inherently longer than oral ones and nobody transcribes the French/Portuguese ones as long. It counts as a heavy, two-moraic syllable. It might have been an [ʊ̃], the difference is more theoretical than practical. I assume that [ʊ] after [w~u] was blocked from occurring and remained/dissimilated to [o].
- whether it was [iʲ] or [ɪʲ], [uʷ] or [ʊʷ] would be hard to decide even if we had recordings (the former soon merged with [eʲ] to boot). Similarly, the English *meed, mood* actually have diphthongs starting in a lax vowel in most varieties, phonemically analysed as /iy/, /uw/.
- I've managed to get a direct line to the Underworld, and Caesar's feedback was positive. I quote: ACCÉPÍ AVSCVLTÁVÍ APPROBÁVÍ

Comment: it sounds plausible, and goes seamlessly from hodie to ianuae. playing it at 50% speed, the very end sounds like the ey of grey, whereas with ianuae, the ae sounds like the y of dry, ie an ai sound. what is your reason for these 2 ae's to be pronounced differently? how do you personally define a diphthong? the um of uum seems to have become om, are you saying the m is nasalising the preceding u? ie that the m doesnt occur after but is a modifier of the previous u?

Comment: @Commenter Any difference between the two ae's is due to one being absolute-final and the other not (the final one is smoother), but none of them sounds like the ey of grey to me. Could be that you're expecting the final /ay/ to sound closer to /ah/ as in English.—A diphthong is two vocalic segments inside one syllable nucleus.—Yes, final M in Latin isn't pronounced as [m] unless p/b/m follows - it spells a nasal without a definite place of articulation, realised as nasalisation when final. There should be a few discussions of this here ("final m"), and there's decent info on Wikipedia

Comment: regarding whether it sounds like ey could be the accent you learnt, the ending sounds like tray to me,  but with a rolled r, where "tray" with standard british english rhymes with "grey". a british accent transliteration of your audio would be "hod ee yay yanoo why dom oo om soon tar tray", where hod rhymes with rod, ee rhymes with he, yay rhymes with may, the vowels of yanoo are the same as those of salute, dom rhymes with tom, oo rhymes with zoo, om like with tom. it may depend on how your ears are tuned. your brain rejigs your perceptions eg hypnosis can totally change perception.

Comment: if you looked at some chinese text, 附近的盒子里有免费的钱 you wouldnt perceive much, but a chinese person would perceive some information, and say open a nearby box, because the text said in chinese some money is available in the box for anyone to have. when you listen to a foreign language, you will perceive it relative to the languages you currently know.

Comment: @Commenter I can hear the a in the diphthong, though I will admit it's said more quickly. Note that it shouldn't be a full "eye" sound, unless perhaps this were oratory and the sound was enunciated very carefully for emphasis.

Comment: @Commenter I agree with your remarks. Myself I have a pretty good understanding - both intuitive and scientific - of how humans perceive language. I agree that it may sound closer to /ey/ than to /ay/, especially in those accents with a more open first part of the former diphthong. The first part of the English /ay/ also tends to be strictly back and much longer than the second, so [ɑːɪ]. This is especially noticeable in British English and in the stereotypical Chinese accent. The Latin /ae/ tends towards the vowel [ɛ], which is the vowel that begins /ey/. In Australia /ay/ is even rounded.

Comment: @Unbrutal_Russian  learning a new language you typically have to retrain your ear and even your tongue, eg I am trying to both perceive and say the long versus short vowels, in particular words with 2 long vowels are a challenge eg vīdistī. It took me a long time to make sense of Berlin german r. I think it is said with the zone from the soft palette to the uvula depending on the person or word, approximated by say a british h sound, which is lighter than the russian kh sound (symbol x).

Comment: one further thing, american phonetics is sparser than british. I had a computer with the speech program used by Stephen Hawkings, and wanted to make the program speak with a british accent. And it was IMPOSSIBLE! not even to come close to a british accent. british english has more and subtler vowels than american. I have enumerated 11 different unvarying british vowel sounds. I think this is why Hawkings speaks with an american accent via the program, despite being british!

Comment: the 11 vowel sounds are of the following words: hat, hut, hot, put, hoot, heat, hit, hem, her, harp, hawk. If you say any 2 of those vowels the same, then you arent using a standard british accent. Americans for instance will say hut and hot the same. And people from the north of England will probably say hut and put the same vowel.

Comment: @Unbrutal_Russian when I first got glasses, the image my left eye saw was much smaller than what the right eye saw, as my left eye is short sighted, right eye long sighted. I couldnt merge the images, was seeing double. The optician said I needed to keep wearing and it will eventually work. Eventually my brain merged the 2 images perfectly. With the glasses on, perfectly merged images despite different sizes. Take the glasses off also perfectly merged! And instantly perfectly merged, with or without glasses.

Comment: @Commenter Yes, it's well-known that GenAmE makes relatively less contrasts, although it's distinguished by plenty of older and even new distinctions as well. I agree with and appreciate your remarks on human perception. But I think this is the right time to repeat something I repeat quite often: it's not very productive to try talking about Latin phonetics using American English equivalents, because GAE has at most one vowel that is exactly the same as in Latin, which is the vowel of *seed*, but even that isn't true on the /iy/ analysis (in AmE unlike BE it's not often audibly diphthongised).

Comment: By the way, [positively no American accent](https://www.quora.com/Do-Americans-pronounce-pairs-of-words-like-hut-and-hot-differently) pronounces hut and hot the same.

Comment: I was thinking more of not and nut, but coz the main words begun with h, I put hot and hut. word order disambiguates such things. Youtube says its just a difference of length: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OgI3sa8NhFE  so is same sound, just different length. speak fast and AmE not becomes nut! whereas british english a totally different sound

Comment: @Commenter The first consonant has no influence on this, -ot and -ut are distinguished in all varieties to my knowledge. In some AmE varieties it's only length, in others they vowel is completely different (those where the nut vowel is basically the schwa). Anyway, the fact that you didn't hear any difference between those two is a nice illustration of what you say about human perception - I doubt I could convince a monolingual Russian speaker that these two vowels were different even in a century.